# View vs Tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Table where I save daily data `TDay`.

```
Task    | Time  | Day | Month | Year |
--------------------------------------
Cooking | 20min | 21  | 03    | 2015 |
Reading | 20min | 21  | 03    | 2015 |
Smiling | 20min | 21  | 03    | 2015 |
Washing | 20min | 21  | 03    | 2015 |
Cooking | 20min | 22  | 03    | 2015 |
Reading | 20min | 22  | 03    | 2015 |
Smiling | 20min | 22  | 03    | 2015 |
Washing | 20min | 22  | 03    | 2015 |
Watching| 20min | 01  | 04    | 2015 |
Washing | 20min | 01  | 04    | 2015 |
Reading | 20min | 01  | 04    | 2015 |
Ironing | 20min | 01  | 04    | 2015 |
```

Now i would need a VIEW or a Table TWeek and TMonth that gathers those results

`TWeek`

```
Task    | Time  | Week | Year |
-------------------------------
Cooking | 40min | 12   | 2015 |
Reading | 40min | 12   | 2015 |
Smiling | 40min | 12   | 2015 |
Washing | 40min | 12   | 2015 |
```

`TMonth`

```
Task    | Time  | Month | Year |
-------------------------------
Cooking | 40min | 03    | 2015 |
Reading | 40min | 03    | 2015 |
Smiling | 40min | 03    | 2015 |
Washing | 40min | 03    | 2015 |
Watching| 20min | 04    | 2015 |
Washing | 20min | 04    | 2015 |
Reading | 20min | 04    | 2015 |
Ironing | 20min | 04    | 2015 |
```

So what I am doing is to gather the results daily and sum the up for a week and a month. The Problem is that I am expecting a lot of data.

Should I use views for that or should I write a small programm that fills tables? Or is it smarter to make a Select where I sum up the data? In the and I will represent a result.

Comment: Why not just have a 'TDAY' table with all data and then TWEEK and TMONTH views which are selects from TDAY group by week / Year?

Comment: Just go with a view until you know you have a performance issues.  Database is pretty efficient.   View is nice in that it not materialized - it does  not use disk space for data.

Comment: I was thnking about using views. Are they fast enough with sqlite or should I avoid them anyway because they can be bottlenecks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision on whether to use a view or summary tables is entirely dependent on your performance needs.  In either case, you can get the system to work.

With a view, you implement the logic one time.  For instance:

```
select task, sum(time) as time, month, year
from tday
group by task, month year
```

for the second summary.

With summary tables, you need to keep the data up-to-date.  Perhaps you can do this when loading the data.  More likely, you will need a separate job or triggers on the table to maintain consistency.

The additional work load for summary tables, along with the increased difficulty of maintaining the system, are why views are often preferred.  Some databases support a construct called *materialized view*, but I don't think SQLite has an equivalent construct.

A typical approach is to start with views.  If you have performance problems, then investigate alternatives.  Materializing the summaries is one common solution.